# PHP MySQLi not updating

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to make a form where I can update two fields one field is going be `admin_welcomebox` and `admin_author` and I'm trying update it by the id so here go my code

```
<div class="col-lg-6">                      
    <div class="panel panel-color panel-inverse">                               
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Welcome Box Update</h3>
        </div>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "trres";
                $password = "sss";
                $dbname = "txxxs";

                // Create connection
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }

                $sql = "UPDATE admin_news SET welcomebox = '{$admin_news}' SET author = {$admin_author} id='{$id}'";

                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "<h4 class='bg-success'>You have updated admin welcome box.</h4>";
                } else {
                    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."');</script>";
                }
                $conn->close();
            }
        ?>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="welcomebox">Welcome Box</label>
                    <textarea type="text" name="welcomebox" id="welcomebox" placeholder="Enter Your Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="author">Author Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control" / >
                </div>                                          
                <div class="form-group text-right m-b-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
                        Update Info
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>                                 
        </div>                                              
    </div>                              
</div>
```

When I try update it just refresh the page nothing else.

Comment: you're not using UPDATE/SET correctly. RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html and checking for errors would have thrown you a syntax error. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php which you failed to mention as per your `$conn->error`.

Comment: `$id` is undefined in your code, so right away error reporting would have thrown you an `undefined variable id` notice about it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check for errors again... as stated in my other comment up there (if you're reading these, that is). As are `$admin_news` and `$admin_author`, so where are those coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has invalid syntax. This is wrong:

```
UPDATE admin_news SET welcomebox = '{$admin_news}' SET author = {$admin_author} id='{$id}'
```

The right MySQL syntax for `UPDATE` is

```
UPDATE admin_news SET welcomebox = 'value', author = 'value' WHERE id='id'
```

More in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Moreover, where do you define `$admin_news`, `$admin_author` and `$id`? I do not see any variable definition in your code.

Comment: No inside the database its a id set at 1 a welcomebox and a author i just need the welcomebox and author updated.

Comment: *Um....* why did you go and remove the OP's form stuff in an edit? http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35665109/2

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, my bad, I considered it useless

Comment: Thing is: new visitors to the question may ask questions like: *"do your form elements all have name attributes and form tags with a post method?"* - Or, *"Does the submit button have a name attribute?"* type of thing. That's usually the first thing I ask/look for in a question usually.

Comment: @Nordenheim Thanks ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: Now, the OP hasn't assigned any POST arrays to any of their variables, and Lord knows where those are (if any), as stated in [yet another comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665109/php-mysqli-not-updating#comment59010666_35665109) under the question, to which I've gotten no response. Plus, their track record on answer acceptance isn't too hot, nor lukewarm. More like cold as *Market fish on ice.* Those right there, are major missing pieces to the puzzle, db schema etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well, I hope he just manages to figure the rest on his own and all the comments and answers are somehow helpful.

Comment: @Nordenheim They have enough to go on for sure. An effort on their part will be most beneficial. Ok... I'm moving on. *ciao for now*.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define `$admin_news` ,`$admin_author` and `$id` as well. define first.

Try this `code` :-

```
<div class="col-lg-6">                      
<div class="panel panel-color panel-inverse">                               
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Welcome Box Update</h3>
    </div>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "trres";
            $password = "sss";
            $dbname = "txxxs";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            $id=$_POST['id'];
            $admin_news=$_POST['welcomebox']; 
            $admin_author=$_POST['author']; 

            $sql = "UPDATE admin_news SET welcomebox = '$admin_news', author = $admin_author where id=$id";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "<h4 class='bg-success'>You have updated admin welcome box.</h4>";
            } else {
                echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."');</script>";
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
    ?>


    <div class="panel-body">
            <form method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /> <!-- put here your id  --> 
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="welcomebox">Welcome Box</label>
                    <textarea type="text" name="welcomebox" id="welcomebox"                       placeholder="Enter Your Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="author">Author Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control" / >
                </div>                                          
                <div class="form-group text-right m-b-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
                        Update Info
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>                                 
        </div>                                              
    </div>                              
</div>
```